# URL connection not working in applet

Tags: java, security, applet, request, bufferedreader

I am trying to run this code in java applet:

```
package test;
import java.applet.Applet;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class DrawExample extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        try {
            g.drawString("CODE:",50, 30);
            URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
            URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();      
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            int i=65;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                g.drawString(inputLine,50, i);
                i=i+15;
            }
            in.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }          
    } 
}
```

It runs fine if I am running this code from Eclipse as an applet, however if I am trying to run it embedded in the web page I get only "CODE:". The code freezes at this line :

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
```

Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this signed applet. Unsigned Applet can open network connection from the server from where they were originated from. Applet security model does not allow then to open the network connection to non-origination server

Have a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

To confirm this you can try to open the stream from the server where this applet is hosted.

Comment: I am not sure I am absolutely new in this field. I just created such code, compiled it and used html page to display it's contents.

Comment: Have look at link given above

Comment: *"I am not sure I am absolutely new in this field"* Developing applets when you apparently do not know of the (browser based) Java Console indicates a steep learning curve ahead.  As an aside.  Sites like Google and Yahoo have typically resisted access by 'programmatic means' - such as an applet on your site.

Comment: @ejb_guy *"To confirm this you can try to open the stream from the server where this applet is hosted."*  Good idea.  Get the URL of the document base and read that.

Comment: Thank you for responses and a useful link. The information about signed and unsigned applets was really useful. However I gave yahoo just as an example, what I am actually trying to do is to make a 3 level architecture where applet gets data through XML from server side code which access database. So this connection to localhost server should be available in unsigned applet too as applet is hosted in it(or am I missing something?). However this doesn't work, moreover I have discovered that some URL addresses of remote servers actually work with existing configuration! I am confused...

Comment: The problem was that I tried to make an URL request to localhost from HTML file which was stored in the local file system (for testing purposes). When I put the file in localhost server everything worked fine. Thanks for help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign your java applet. It works when you run in Eclipse, because eclipse creates a file called **java.policy.applet** with the following content.

```
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Tue Apr 16 17:20:59 EDT 2002*/
/* DO NOT EDIT */

grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

In order to make your applet run outside of Eclipse, you must sign it:

1. Compile applet - javac Applet.java
2. Make a JAR File - jar cvf Applet.jar Applet.class
3. Generate Keys
4. Sign the JAR File
5. Export the Public Key Certificate
   ...

It goes on and on, it's a very long process. You can follow all the steps [in this page](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html#example)